# how to pass SESSION_id after user login?

Tags: php

i want to pass id session variable including i have successfully passed email as session variable. if a user is logged in with emailand password... i want to store his/her id as session..
here is my php code:

```
<?php
 session_start();
//Database Configuration File
include('database.php');
error_reporting(1);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Getting username/ email and password

    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $sessionid = session_id();


    // Fetch data from database on the basis of username/email and password
    $sql ="SELECT email ,password FROM student WHERE (email=:email)";
    $query= $conn -> prepare($sql);
    $query-> bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> execute();
    $results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            $passwordhash = $row->password;

        }



        //verifying Password
        $pass =password_verify($password,$passwordhash);



        if ($pass) 
        {
            $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];


            header('location:http://localhost/kridha/teacherdashboard.php');
        }
         else 
         {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('wrong credtials');
            window.location='teacher.html';
            </script>";
        }

}
//if username or email not found in database
else{
echo "<script>alert('User not registered with us');</script>";
  }
}
?>
```

i have tried various methods but it didn't work.please dont delte this question. i have tried all several questions!!help!!

Comment: Try to clarify what you want to do exactly with the $sessionid variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session_id(); function to get session id

```
$sessionid = session_id();
```

Comment: $sessionid = session_id();

Comment: i have update the code with correction as you have said..is this correct way?? with this code i am not able to login ...i am using session id to login

Comment: i am not able to login because i hae put this code on dashboard  ```<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
    // not logged in
    header('Location: teacher.html');
    exit();
}
?>```